# Windows 10 Kiosk mode - Assigned Access with startup scripts

Tags: windows-10, kiosk

Is it possible to run startup scripts that will run WAMP in the background and for instance start some other applications like Chrome with kiosk parameters?

Answer (score 1):

assigned access accounts will only be able to launch one program, which is essentially the application you assign to it. If you launch WAMP through a logon script and then try to run a second program you'll encouter an error condition.

Answer (score 0):

I used a script that stops the process explorer.exe and therefor disabling all ui elements that could get out of kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

Windows scheduled tasks still work so you can provide a startupscript that way.